# Panasonic scanner not working on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 18.04, usb, 19.04, scanner

I have a Panasonic KX-MB 1500 multifunction laser printer/scanner. This worked perfectly until Ubuntu 16.04. Since then (including on 19.04) only the printer works, not the scanner.

Panasonic provides drivers for Ubuntu & Redhat here: http://panasonic.net/pcc/support/fax/common/table/linuxdriver.html

Upon installing the scanner driver, no front-end can see the scanner. Here is the output of lsusb & sane-find-scanner. Running sane-find-scanner or scanImage -L as sudo does not make any difference.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0461:4e22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
**Bus 003 Device 006: ID 04da:0f0b Panasonic (Matsushita)** 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04d9:1203 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ sudo sane-find-scanner 

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not fetch string descriptor: Input/output error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

Comment: Did you install http://cs.psn-web.net/support/fax/common/file/Linux_ScanDriver/panamfs-scan-1.3.0-x86_64.tar.gz?

Comment: Yes. This driver works on ubuntu versions 15.04 and 15.10. But I have not been able to get this working on any ubuntu since 17.xx on.

Comment: See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322749

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestion heynnema.
I had to install libusb-0.1-4 and then everything worked like charm on 19.04. It would likely work on earlier versions too.
I found no trace of this missing library in /var/log/syslog though.

Thanks!

Comment: I confirm that `sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4` on Ubuntu 20.04 also makes my Panasonic KX-MB2000 working.